# "¿Sip o nop?" ¿Cuál es el origen de estas variaciones?

Tags: coloquialismos, sufijos, jerga-internet, estilo

He escuchado y leído bastante "sip" en vez de "sí" y "nop" en vez de "no". Hay también otras variantes como "nope" y la chilena "yap" (sí).

Lo que se dice en internet (en sitios de opinión básica como WordReference Forums o Yahoo Answers) es que probablemente proviene del mundo del chat, aunque yo lo he escuchado también en palabra hablada.

Cuando yo era joven (uff...) se dio la costumbre de sufijar algunas palabras con terminaciones que evocaran el inglés (*tranquilein, lolein, amiguein, amiguéitor*...), haciendo que las conversaciones se escucharan más floridas. Me imagino que pasa lo mismo en este caso, es un recurso estilístico de tipo jerga, pero no entiendo por qué se eligió la terminación *-p*. No creo que sea un anglicismo, porque no es una terminación típica del inglés.

¿De dónde viene esa "p"? ¿Cuándo empieza a usarse? ¿Es habitual en los distintos países?

Comment: En México, además de utilizar estas variaciones, también se utiliza Nel (para No) y Simon (para Si).

Comment: Yo empecé a ver *sip* y *nop* en los chats pero mucho antes de existir internet decíamos *sipi* y *nopi* al intercambiar cromos, así que puede haber variaciones similares en distintos países o regiones.

Comment: Sí es habitual en inglés. En Estados Unidos, al menos, *yep* y *nope* son bastante habituales.

Comment: Sipiriri, nopororo también usados en México.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente no es un anglicismo.

En Chile, se dice como respuesta afirmativa: "**sí, po**", y como negativa: "**no, po**". No es común ver escritas estas frases así; y usualmente se escuchan "sipo" y "nopo". Sin embargo, "po" es una palabra distinta, que viene de "puh", cuyo origen es"pues", descendiendo así etimológicamente del latín *post*, que significaba *después*, según [etimologías.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?po). Esta evolución fonética tiende, como puedes ver, a la *desaparición* de sonidos, debido a nuestro hábito de descuidar la pronunciación de la 's' final. La entrada en etimologias.dechile.net indica que algo semejante ocurre en Andalucía. ¿Qué cuesta, entonces, quitar de la escritura informal la vocal cuyo propósito era solamente acompañar y respaldar a la "s"?

Esto ha ocurrido desde hace tanto tiempo en Chile que muchos no saben de dónde viene; cuando yo de pequeño (años 2000-2001) preguntaba "qué significa el **po**?", me decían: "Es como --no sé po-- decir sípo es como decir ¡*sí*, po!", dando a entender vagamente que "po" viene siendo simplemente un sonido al fin de la oración para dar énfasis.

Pero una vez más crecido (año 2007), fui al Perú andino, donde oí de personas de edad (en el campo, donde recién estaba llegando la internet): "sí-pe" y "no-pe", junto con el elegantísimo "ya-pe". En el alto Perú se suele hablar con bastante cuidado, por lo que indico con un '-' en las transcripciones una pausa infinitésima entre el "sí" y el "pues" mutilado. Pero otra vez, ¿cuál es el problema? ¡Quitemos de la escritura informal a aquella 'e' tan insignificante!

En Bolivia, más tarde (2015-17), viví en Santa Cruz, en las tierras bajas. Allí se conocen a los *collas* de las tierras altas por (entre otros rasgos, claro) su hablar: "¿Qué c-sita me-s dicho?" (cosita, me has), y el famoso "si-ps". De tanto, un señor en Cochabamba, César Patzi, nombró a su blog así: http://sips-nops-yaps.blogspot.com/?m=1:
[image: sips-nops-yaps]

Recorcheteo: El sip y el nop vienen sencillamente por la pérdida de letras del "**pues**".

Comment: Qué buena respuesta y qué bonito recorrido vital que describes. En [¿Quiénes somos?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/1674) vamos apuntando voluntariamente de dónde somos los usuarios de este sitio, por si apetece unirte a la  lista. Por cierto, ¿qué es el _recorcheteo_? Veo que un "corchete" vendría a ser una grapadora ¿?

Comment: @fedorqui El corchete es la _grapa_; acabo de darme cuenta (¡no tenía idea!) por una búsqueda rápida después de leer tu comentario que es un regionalismo (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/corchetear.2317467/), junto con el verbo derivado _corchetear_ y el requetecontra-derivado que yo utilicé para decir "pongo la segunda grapa [cerrando el argumento decisivamente]". Muchas gracias por la amable invitación, voy a ir más tarde. Saludos

Comment: ¿Oye pues te parece si formulo una pregunta sobre _corcheteo_ y así más gente aprende el concepto?

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Claro que sí! Yo no escribiría hasta la tarde (ahora son las 9.00 aquí en Chile), pero sería interesante saber la extensión de su uso en otros lugares-me pareció haber visto su uso en un libro escolar centroamericano. Lo buscaré después.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando yo era pequeño, no era raro decir "sipi" en vez de "sí" o "nopo" en vez de "no". Esto es un tipo de [jerigonza](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerigonza) bastante habitual entre niños, consistente en añadir a cada palabra (o incluso a cada sílaba) otra sílaba adicional compuesta de *p* + la vocal más relevante de la sílaba anterior. Ejemplo:

> Ayer Paquito me dejó su boli.
>   Ayeper Paquitopo mepe dejopo supu bolipi.
>   Apayeper Papaquipitopo mepe depejopo supu bopolipi.

Nadie esperaría que de adultos hablemos así, pero es posible que las palabras más cortas o más utilizadas, "sipi" / "nopo" sí que hayan conseguido sobrevivir en nuestro vocabulario convertidas en unos "sip" / "nop" usados para darle cierto aire jovial a la respuesta.
Lo mismo aplicaría a otras variantes como "yap", "valep", etc.

Comment: ¿Dónde vivías de pequeño?

Comment: @Conrado el usuario que respondió (y cuya cuenta después eliminó) es de España

Answer (score 3):

En estos casos de jerga de internet es muy complicado establecer cuál es el origen, pues probablemente se fraguó en un chat remoto que dio lugar a que otra gente lo adoptara, etc. hasta que emergió a contextos escritos más persistentes.

En [Por un sip o por un nop](http://www.lavanguardia.com/opinion/articulos/20140217/54401243547/sip-nop-magi-camps-opi.html) discutían allá por 2014 sobre las dos posibles hipótesis:

> Por un lado, la que apunta que el resultado es una fusión del adverbio con el emoticono de sacar la lengua (:-P), un gesto atrevido o juguetón. Así, sí:P ha acabado siendo sip.
>
> La segunda línea habla simplemente de una forma simpática de responder. En este caso hay quien añade una clara influencia del inglés. En esta lengua, ya hace tiempo que al lado del *yes* se utiliza *yeah*, *yup* y, también, *yep*. Y la variante *nope* de la negación también la recogen algunos diccionarios. En estas cosas, los vocabularios ingleses siempre van por delante.

A mí personalmente me convence más la segunda, pues el uso de `:P` es bastante nuevo y no creo que existiera allá por los años 80 (cuando DGaleano, como explica en los comentarios, ya lo escuchó), mientras que [el uso del inglés *yep* se remonta a 1889](https://www.etymonline.com/word/yep), que como mínimo es anterior a los años 80.

Comment: Como comenté antes lo he oído desde los 80 y no creo que tenga nada que ver con los chat.

Comment: @DGaleano en tal caso tendría más sentido la segunda opción, que [es bastante anterior a internet](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/362788/37429), pues tendría casi un siglo de antigüedad.

Comment: @wal añadí uno aún mejor

Answer (score 2):

En Bogotá-Colombia, a mediados de los 90's, para mí era bastante común el "sip", "sipi", "nop" y "nopo".

También jugué a hablar en jeringonza como menciona user13628, cantábamos el villancico:

> "Hacia Belén va una burra rin rin,  yo me remendaba, yo me remendé,
> yo me hice un remiendo, yo me lo quité",

como:

> "Hapaciapa Bepelénpen vapa upunapa bupurrapa rinpin rinpin,  yopo mepe
> repemenpedapaba, yopo mepe repemenpedépe,  yopo mepe hipicepe unpu
> repemipenpedopo, yopo mepe lopo quipitépe"

El juego de palabras también buscaba usar y crear palabras similares o que iniciaran con la misma sílaba, así como en México usan "Simón" para "si". Yo usaba "símbolo" y "nómbolo".
Hoy en día es muy frecuente escuchar "sisas", "cilantros" y "ciclas"(abreviatura para bicicletas)

Y créeme, a mediados de los 90's no se conocía el internet en Colombia.

Answer (score 1):

"Sip" y sobre todo "nop" lo he leído mucho antes de que existiera Internet, en libros publicados en España y México en los años 50 - 60. No tengo fuentes, pero en alguna novela de Zane Grey eran las respuestas lacónicas de un vaquero o pistolero.

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde para contestar, pero más vale tarde...

La costumbre empieza por la operación NOP existente en lenguajes ensambladores desde hace tiempo. Algunos usuarios de estos lenguajes empezaron a contestar nop por no, luego sip por si y posteriormente valep por vale.

NOP significa literalmente NO-OPERATION, o sea una operación que no hace nada.