# Where is it common to add a syllable or syllables to words for humor?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación, humor

El sentido de humor popular chileno permite agregar una sílaba o sílabas a una palabra, usualmente al final, haciendo un juego fonético paralelo a la frase hablada.

A veces se puede responder de manera similar, haciendo un juego entre dos personas. Este juego puede durar hasta que a uno de los participantes se le acaban las municiones, o simplemente podrían ser unos pocos turnos. Por ejemplo, un saludo entre conocidos que se encuentran en la ferretería podría ser:

-Buen día, ¿**cómo te ba**ila?

Y la respuesta podría ser:

-**Mal**ena, que no he podido trabajar pa' pagar las cuentas. (*que le va mal*)

(O al contrario podría ser)

-**Vien**to y marea. (*que le va bien*)

O al terminar un trabajo, podríamos decir:

-**Listo**ngo, ya terminamos.

O yo te estoy enseñando cómo dibujar un árbol. Luego tú lo haces bien, y me muestras tu dibujo. Yo te diría:

-¡École!

O incluso podría decir:

-¡Ecolecuá!

Ambos son distorsiones leves de "¡Eso!" con sílabas adicionales.

O me podrías decir que nos juntemos en la esquina mañana para tomar un café, y yo diría:

-**¡Vale**ntina! ¿A qué hora?

Cuando yo lo hacía en Bolivia (Santa Cruz), siempre tenía que explicar mi significado, y no le hallaban la gracia al chiste.

¿Donde más se acepta este tipo de juego fonético como chiste?

**edit**:
Encontré un ejemplo de costumbre mexicana, en un comentario de @Hoose sobre una [pregunta sobre sip y nop](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24338/sip-o-nop-cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-estas-variaciones):

> En México, además de utilizar estas variaciones, también se utiliza Nel (para No) y Simon (para Si).

Comment: "École/ecolecuá" parece más bien tomado del italiano "Eccolo/Eccolo qua", que significa exactamente eso, "helo (aquí)", "aquí está".

Comment: @wimi Has dicho verdad: https://context.reverso.net/translation/italian-english/Eccolo+qua ... ¿Por qué nadie me lo había enseñado antes?

Comment: @wimi: También "eccole" y "eccole qua": en estas expresiones "le" es el pronombre femenino plural de complemento directo.

Comment: @Charo lo he pensado, pero visto el ejemplo de la pregunta ("un dibujo"), parece que se refiere a "eccolo" y casi suena a leísmo... Sería interesante saber si en Chile dirían "Écolas" o también "École" si en lugar de "tu dibujo" fueran "tus cuentas".

Comment: @wimi _yo_ diría de igual forma "ecole", pero no soy nativo-puede que yo haya aprendido mal. Voy a preguntar... Luego editaré.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [esta página](http://portenisima.com.ar/notadetalle.php?notaid=117) se encuentran algunas de las expresiones de ese tipo que se usan en Argentina. Debo decir que sólo he oído algunas, y que son sumamente coloquiales, casi denotativas de un nivel cultural bajo por su carácter excesivamente popular. Las que alguna vez he oído son:

No pasa naranja = No pasa nada

Graciela = Gracias

De Nadia = de nada

De nalgas = de nada

Todo viento = todo bien

¿Y Johnny/Yolanda? = ¿Y yo?

¿Y Boston/Bosnia? = ¿Y vos?

¿Qué acelga? = ¿Qué hacés/hacen?

¿Qué talco? = ¿Qué tal?

Creo que este tipo de expresiones guardan cierto parentesco con otras de corte eufemístico que mencionaba en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21374/eufemismos-en-la-lengua-coloquial).

Otro ejemplo es:

Quedó cortina = Quedó corto/a

Comment: Gracias por los links, los dos son útiles- exactamente lo que estaba buscando.